# Why IDL modification causes crash in C++ projects but not in VB projects?

Tags: c++, com, vb6, idl, com-automation

We have a C++ project that exposes some classes via COM Automation and thus has an `IDL` file.

Whenever we added new functions to the classes in the `IDL` (without changing the UUID), the other C++ projects that use the classes (but not the new functions) need to be rebuilt with the new `IDL` or they will crash but the other VB6 ActiveX projects don't crash.

Why do we need to rebuild the C++ projects but VB projects are okay?

Comment: Are your C++ projects using those C++ classes directly, by any chance (as opposed to working via COM interfaces)? Show some code demonstrating exactly how your C++ client gets an instance of the server and calls one method on it.

Answer (score 5):

At a guess, you're probably defining your objects in VB as just `Object`s, something like this:

```
Dim YourObject as Object
Set YourObject = CreateObject("YourComponent.YourObject")
```

If so, you're forcing VB to go through the automation interface (IDispatch). Basically, it doesn't know what type you're going to assign to `YourObject` until run-time, so it has to invoke methods on that object via IDispatch::Invoke. To do that, it looks up all the information it needs for an invocation from the object itself at run time.

By contrast, your C++ code is probably early-bound, which means offsets into the COM object's vtable are compiled directly into your code. In that case, when/if you change the code so those offsets aren't valid any more, the code will fail horribly.

Comment: how to make the C++ projects behave similarly to VB ?

Comment: You can [call methods via IDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221694.aspx) in C++ as well (though it's fairly painful and clumsy).

Comment: @afriza: Another option is to recompile the C++ projects after each COM server modification.

Comment: +1. afriza, if you provided some Vb6 code, it would be helpful. At the moment Jerry is guessing (although it is a good guess).